# как сделать ссылку на гитхаб, чтобы открывалась главная страница html

Tags: html, css, git, github

пишу так 
[посмотреть]в скобках https://Lilechkalove.github.io/project1/repair-design
repair-design - название моего html файла
неужели нужно создать ещё 1 ветку?

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вы хотите чтобы страница открывалась не как код, тогда этот html файл должен располагаться в ветке `gh-pages` ИЛИ репозиторий должен называться `<username>.github.io`

Comment: Большое спасибо, так работает!